# Primes with argc and argv

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in Codejudge which I write a command line program which reads a space separated list of integers from the command line and prints the ordered sublist consisting of the input prime numbers.

I tried numerous times but I can't seem to work
this is input argument:

```
9308 2034 9466 283 7949 1153 7241 5341 4693 6910 6852 5540 8015 9305 5697 1395 4727 9159 8661 1367 6096 2911 4797 8025 2593 5460 5767 5543 2429 8371 6024 2343 285 8657 9869 5388 5295 6279 3084 9573 6980 2362 1565 5134 5185 1991 7142 3699 5937 4151 3044 2468 8005 1603 662 2989 752 6971 3152 3681 9743 653 4542 719 2081 5772 9179 4034 5904 5494 1653 251 130 6646 2835 2260 8998 7464 112 2179 6592 8502 7381 5990 6681 8237 1331 537 2048 3342 9353 7883 1041 621 1022 4569 1421 9592 877 657 7097 2828 6242 2216 387 4605 8017 2784 4509 5818 7959 1612 491 6381 6530 5773 2220 2802 6478 7401 9084 1845 8805 8192 9806 6940 6578 9132 3144 8793 4854 1087 3238 8622 419 346 2598 1194 5766 4626 4740 6191 8639 7948 9833 3117 232 5839 8726 4863 4532 3498 6717 4874 3496 2951 5750 6982 1779 9614 9519 5980 3245 2698 6771
```

etc.

```
  #include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> input;
    std::vector<int> output;
    for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
        input.push_back(std::atoi(argv[a]));
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        if (input.at(i) % 2 != 0 && (input.at(i) % 3 != 0 || input.at(i) / 3 == 1) && (input.at(i) % 5 != 0 || input.at(i) / 5 == 1) /*&& input.at(i)*input.at(i)% input.at(i)!=0*/) {
            output.push_back(input.at(i));
            count++;
        }
    }
    sort(output.begin(), output.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        std::cout << output[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
1 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241
```

actual result:

```
1 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 49 53 59 61 67 71 73 77 79 83 89 91 97 101 103 107 109 113 119 121 127 131 133 137 139 143 149 151 157 161 163 167 169 173 179 181 187 191 193 197 199 203 209 211 217 221 223 227 229 233 239 241
```

there are difference between the expected and the actual.

keep in mind that the vector of random numbers are in random orders and not from smallest to largest and they all are

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: FWIW, You really should use two loops the check for primes (or use a function).  Only loop to iterate the list and the other to check all the possible factors.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: *and I am short of time here* -- That is your problem, not ours.  Posts that say "I need this by tomorrow" or "I am short on time" gives the impression that your question deserves priority over others.  If an answer is given today, tomorrow, next week, or next year, that's how it goes.

Comment: Here's a thing; I did, but the result got worse,

Comment: And i know how to debug, but i did try, but i could not get around the square odd numbers and of course the input is a huge vector with thousands of random 4 digits numbers

Comment: @ZainAhmed All you need to do to use the debugger effectively is to change your code to test one number that you know is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
    input.push_back(std::atoi(argv[a]));
}
```

should be

```
for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
    input.push_back(std::atoi(argv[a]));
}
```

The first argument `argv[0]` is the program name.

Comment: that is not the real problem here, the real problem is when the list nr. is a square number.

Comment: @ZainAhmed I think your primality test is just wrong. Simple as that.

Comment: No this is my a part of the whole argument:9308 2034 9466 283 7949 1153 7241 5341 4693 6910 6852 5540 8015 9305 5697 1395 4727 9159 8661 1367 6096 2911 4797 8025 2593 5460 5767 5543 2429 8371 6024 2343 285 8657 9869 5388 5295 6279 3084 9573 6980 2362 1565 5134 5185 1991 7142 3699 5937 4151 3044 2468 8005 1603 662 2989 752 6971 3152 3681 9743 653 4542 719 2081 5772 9179 4034 5904 5494 1653 251 130 6646 2835 2260 8998 7464 112 2179 6592 8502 7381 5990 6681 8237 1331 537 2048 3342 9353 7883 1041 621 1022 4569 1421 9592 877 657 7097 2828 6242 2216 387 4605 8017 2784 4509 5818 7959 1612 491 6381

Comment: @ZainAhmed I don't understand what you mean. Your program isn't working because your test for primes is wrong. You could check that easily enough without running your entire input through your program.

Comment: the first test has this vector: 12 32 34 12 123 31 12 13 8 7 123 89 and the expected result is: 7 13 31 89, which my code did solve, and the second argument is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34, and extracting primes from this vector is solved too, but my issue here is with odd square numbers like 49 (7x7)  121 (11x11) etc.

Comment: Yes exactly, because **your test for primes is incorrect**. It doesn't work for numbers like 49 and 121. How many times does this have to be said? Nathan Oliver said the same thing 18 hours ago.

Comment: Nor does it work for numbers which aren't odd sqaures like 77 for instance.

Comment: Run your program under the debugger with input 49 77 121, see what happens.